# How can I be notified when the scrollers in an NSScrollView with NSScrollerStyleOverlay hide and unhide?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsscrollview

Title says it all. I'd like to get a callback when NSScrollerStyleOverlay scrollers appear and disappear. Things I've tried that don't work:

- `scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller` returns `YES` even when the scroller is hidden.
- `scrollView.horizontalScroller.isHidden` seems to always return `NO`.
- `scrollView.horizontalScroller.alphaValue` seems to always return `1.0`.
- `scrollView.horizontalScroller.frame` doesn't seem to change
  in hidden vs. not hidden states.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you listen to the `NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification` of the `NSScrollView Delegate`? Does that help?

Comment: I assume you mean the NSScrollView's `contentView`. This is what I'm currently doing: listening to that notification, incrementing a counter, then doing a dispatch_after (to wait for the scrollers to go away) in which I check the counter to see if any more bounds changes have occurred, and if not, I conclude that the scroll bars are hidden. This is hacky at best. I'm hoping there's a direct "cause & effect" way to detect this, since scroll bar behavior is changed by a system preference, and what I really want is to know when they show and hide. (i.e. if they're always visible, never notify)

Comment: Yes I did mean that ... I knew that it would be pretty hacky (at best) and didn't think of the point with the preferences ... sorry :(